# MS Word files sometimes read-only after hibernation?

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-word, hibernate, standby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [While editing a document in Word 2007 the document suddenly becomes read only](https://superuser.com/questions/216855/while-editing-a-document-in-word-2007-the-document-suddenly-becomes-read-only)

I've found that sometimes MS Word files become read-only after returning from standby or hibernation.

What could have been the cause of this?

So e.g. if I wanted to cause it to happen now.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean read-only (as shown in the file's properties) or you just can't edit the files?  If you can't edit them it usually means a program still has the file open.  If you load Task Manager and kill all instances of WINWORD.EXE then Word should "let go" of all open files and the files should become editable again.

Of course if another program has the file open instead that wouldn't work, but there are utilities available that can show you which programs have a file open.