# Word 2007 document after one save becomes read-only

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, microsoft-office-2007

I have posted this question before, but there are some new takes on it now.  I have some work documents linked to Excel, they automatically update when I open them.  Initially the problem only happened after around 10 saves of the document, now it happens every second save.  I have created a new document in word and it does not happen now but if I create a document from the one that has this issue, even a blank one not linked to Excel, it will take a few saves with changes, then it turns read only again.  I have tried everything I read on line and nothing has helped.  I got rid of all auto saves, background save, set the folder to not be read only (but it sets itself back telling me there is a file inside that is not changing, but its not the ones I am using anyway).  If I email the file to someone else, they have the same problem with it.  If I make a new file and from scratch, it starts up again eventually.  I make these saves about 20 times a day and all I can do is save as a different name and then delete the old one and resave as the old name, its so frustrating!

Comment: You don't mention trying the accepted solution for the [question](http://superuser.com/questions/216855/while-editing-a-document-in-word-2007-the-document-suddenly-becomes-read-only) which your previous question was deemed a duplicate of (and therefore closed).

Comment: There was never a functional answer given.

Comment: Frank V said "Word 2007 document suddenly becomes read-only". harrymc said "disable the anti-virus for some time to see if this solves the problem.", Frank V said "Haven't had the issue all day. Thank you."

Comment: Its on a corporate anti virus, can't disable it.  Thanks for the suggestion and that may very well be the issue, except I am the only one on the network with this issue.